Write Custom IDs to specific address with OpenOCD (BlueNRG-2)
Hej Folks,
I try to store unique IDs (serialnumbers) of my BlueNRG-2 into there flash.
Currently I program my controllers using OpenOCD. ".\bin\openocd.exe" -f .\scripts\interface\stlink.cfg -f .\scripts\target\bluenrg-x.cfg -c "program application.elf verify reset exit"
I have a reserved memory area at flash where I would like to write IDs (48 Bit) using openOCD.
Kinda, program current application and then write ID to flash.
Currently I use a part of the BLE Stacklib for the reserved space.
The NVM BLE Stacklib is 4kB in size, but uses only ~2kB. So I sneaked 512B from there.
BLOCK_STACKLIB_FLASH_DATA (_MEMORY_FLASH_END_ - FLASH_NVM_DATASIZE + 1) (NOLOAD) :
{
. = ALIGN(2048);

    KEEP(*(.noinit.stacklib_flash_data))
    KEEP(*(.noinit.stacklib_stored_device_id_data))
    
    KEEP(*(.noinit.custom_stored_data))

} \>REGION_NVM

NO_INIT_SECTION(uint8_t custom_stored_data[512], ".noinit.custom_stored_data");

If i look up at what address my custom_stored_data are sitting ((void*)&custom_stored_data) I see they are a at address 0x1007f838. I hoped I could simple use OpenOCD to write to that address.
".\bin\openocd.exe" -f .\scripts\interface\stlink.cfg -f .\scripts\target\bluenrg-x.cfg -c "flash fillb 0x1007f838 0x12"
But that results only into a list of supported commands.
So using telnet and OpenOCD directly I get a new error.
> flash filld 0x1007f838 0x12 1
Start address 0x1007f838 breaks the required alignment of flash bank bluenrg-1.flash
Padding 8 bytes from 0x1007f830
Target not halted
error writing to flash at address 0x10040000 at offset 0x0003f830

Every recommendation is appreciated.
(Sorry for bad english.)
